# How can I define an associated const or type alias in Rust?

Tags: rust

Basically, I just want "shortcuts":

```
impl Foo {
    const c : i32 = 42;
    type V = i32;
    fn bar() -> V { c }
}
```

But the compiler complains with:

```
error: associated constants are experimental (see issue #29646)
```

Comment: `const` inside of `impl` denotes an [associated constant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/associated-constants.html), which is an experimental feature, gated with `associated_consts`. You will need a nightly compiler and a `#![feature(associated_consts)]` attribute in your crate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the error message, associated constants (`const c: i32 = 42`) are experimental.

This means that, unless you switch to a nightly compiler *and* enable the feature, you cannot have constants nested inside implementations or traits.

You can, however, have constants at module scope:

```
const C: i32 = 42;
```

If you fix this, you will get to the next error: associated types are only allowed in *traits* and their implementation, not in "inherent" implementations.

Once again, the work-around is to pull out the type alias at module scope:

```
type V = i32;
```

The following code compiles:

```
const C: i32 = 42;
type V = i32;

struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn bar() -> V { C }
}
```

and with `C` and `V` being private (only accessible within the module) they do not leak.

Comment: Okay, my concrete usecase is a bit more complex. Let's say I want to create a generic shortcut (type alias, but not new type):

  trait KeyValue {
    type Key;
    type Value;
  }

  type HashMapEntry<'a, H: KeyValue> = std::collections::hash_map::OccupiedEntry<'a, H::Key, H::Value>;

The compiler complains with:

  warning[E0122]: trait bounds are not (yet) enforced in type definitions

Comment: @user3612643: I would encourage you to make it a full-blown question, with a MCVE which produces the error you highlight here, it will allow for more space than comments to answer.